# Where are Kronecker's lectures on polynomial resultants?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, resultant, lecture-notes

From [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Resultant.html), which in turn cites Henry Fine's biography [here](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Fine_Henry.html), states:

> Kronecker gave a series of lectures on resultants during the summer of 1885.

Though a search for lectures by Kronecker on resultants turns up nothing. Can these lectures be found anywhere?